# How to make all my images return as cached and not have so many cache misses?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a static image on my home page of a site I'm caching. The stats show hits 607 and misses 181. The image never changes. Why is it not 1 miss and the rest hits?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon CloudFront is a **pull-based content distribution network**, with edge locations in over 50 locations around the world.

Users access a CloudFront distribution via a supplied URL (which can be associated with a `CNAME` record to give turn it into a friendly URL). They will then be **forwarded to the *closest* edge location**.

If that edge location contains a copy of the object and the cache period has not expired, then the object is returned to the user. If the cache period has expired, CloudFront **goes back to the origin** to obtain the Last Modified Date. If the object has not been modified, it will serve the existing object from the cache. If it has expired, it will retrieve the new (modified) version of the object.

If another user accesses the distribution and they are sent to the same cache location, they will receive a copy of the object from the cache. However, if they are sent to **a cache location that does *not* have a copy of the object**, then the retrieval process takes place again for that cache location.

So, answer your question:

- The object might have been retrieved from different locations around the world, hitting different edge locations
- The objects might have expired, requiring a reload
- Users might be retrieving many different objects, which have not previously been cached

Comment: any way to see stats on this activity? I'm worried something is somehow wrong on my end causing so many misses.  Do we have any control over how long these are retained in cloudfront?

Comment: You can activate [CloudFront logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) and obtain this level of detailed information.